# Is there any workaround for URL error when I run python notebook in VS code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am running a python notebook file (.ipynb) in VS Code but faced an error when I read a URL. I've tried the same exact file on jupyter notebook itself and I faced no error there. Can someone advise me on steps to debug this?

Below are the screenshots of my error message.

[image: first part of error message]

[image: second part of error message]

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should not post images of code, please rather paste the code or error itself (links might get broken some day in the future, and text is more readable). Also both your images seem to contain the same thing